# Subprocess streaming stdout hangs after 30 minutes

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a program which continuously reads data from a sensor, prints it to stdout, and flushes stdout. It reads the sensor rather often. I would like my Python program to capture stdout from this program, and do something interesting with the data. I achieve this using the `subprocess` module. Everything works great for around ~30 minutes or so, then all of the sudden the code hangs waiting for the next line.

Here is the relevant code.

```py
with subprocess.Popen(
    run_my_program,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
) as proc:
    for line in proc.stdout:
        do_something(line)
```

My only guess is perhaps `do_something` is slower than the rate of incoming data, which causes the stdout buffer to fill. What happens in the case? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: How to reproduce this behaviour?

Comment: I'm not sure.. I've tried artificially making `do_something` take longer, but there doesn't seem to be any linear impact on when it stops working.

Comment: Do you know how fast the sensor program is sending data?  If you don't you could try to measure it by simply counting the lines from stdout instead of running the possibly time-consuming function do_something.  Until you know some concrete data about how fast the lines arrive, and how slow do_something is, you're just guessing.

Comment: Good suggestion. Did some measuring. The sensor is sending a line of data at around 25Hz. `do_something` seems to be running at around 400Hz so there must be something else going on.